# How does thread join work?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I found a C++ web server [example](https://github.com/eidheim/Simple-Web-Server/) which works based on threads.

I replaced [line 161](https://github.com/eidheim/Simple-Web-Server/blob/master/https_examples.cpp#L161) from

```
server_thread.join();
```

to

```
std::cout<<"Before thread join\n";

server_thread.join();

std::cout<<"5 sec delay starting ...\n";
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(5));
std::cout<<"5 sec delay ended\n";
```

The result obviously shows that the code after `join` is not running.

```
123
{"firstName": "John","lastName": "Smith","age": 25}
John Smith
Before thread join
```

While in my simple example below, the code below `thread_2.join();` runs as well. While it does not run final `std::cout` until both threads are released. What is the logic behind `.join();` does it pause the current thread?

If I want the code after `server_thread.join();` continues running alongside with the server, what is the proper solution?

main.cpp

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void task1() { 
    // do stuff
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"task1 "<<"["<<i<<"]\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

void task2()
{ 
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"task2 "<<"["<<i<<"]\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

int main ()
{
    using namespace boost; 
    std::thread thread_1 = std::thread(task1);
    std::thread thread_2 = std::thread(task2);

    // do other stuff
    thread_2.join();
    thread_1.join();
    // std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    std::cout<<"end of main function\n";
    return 0;
}
```

results:

```
task1 [0]
task2 [0]
task1 [1]
task2 [1]
task1 [2]
task2 [2]
task1 [task2 [33]
]
task2 [4]
task1 [4]
task2 [5]
task1 [5]
task2 task1 [[66]
]
task2 [task1 [77]
]
task2 task1 [[88]
]
task2 [9]
task1 [9]
end of main function
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join

Comment: @JanHudec, but why in my `main.cpp` the thread is not blocked?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis, how do you say in the first example the current thread is joined? is `server_thread` equal to the current thread?

Comment: @ar2015 What do you mean by "the thread is not blocked". You call `join()` on the main thread, which blocks the main thread until the referenced thread terminates. And from your output, that is what happens. Join blocks the current thread waiting for the referenced thread to terminate.

Comment: @dhke, I mean that flow of `main` is not blocked. If the main thread is blocked, how does the second `join` runs alongside with the first `join`?

Comment: @ar2015 I think I get your confusion: The joins don't run in parallel, they run sequentially. That doesn't mean, however, that the threads don't continue to run in the background. `thread1` and `thread2` both happily continue their work. What happens for the `join()` call is that the main thread is blocked until first `thread2` finishes and then `thread1` finishes. But while the main thread is blocked waiting for `thread2`, `thread1` is also chucking along in parallel.

Comment: @dhke, my mistake was even worse. I had assumed the threads start running when they join. while they start running from when they are defined via `std::thread` `constructor`.

Answer (score 2):

`thread::join` waits until the thread has completed.

In your first example, `server_thread` keeps running more-or-less indefinitely; the purpose of the `join` is to keep the `main` method from returning prematurely (since that would kill the server thread).

In your second example, the thread just does a quick task and then closes, so the `join` returns quickly.

Comment: I got confused. In my second example, according to the results, both threads are working simultaneously and it is not like `task2` runs after `task1` finishes.

Comment: @ar2015: Right, because you start both threads and then wait for them both to complete. If you changed it so that you waited for `task1` to complete before you started `task2`, or if you changed it so that `task2` itself waited for `task1` to complete before it started doing stuff, then you would not see this interleaving.

Comment: I have done a big mistake. I assumed the thread starts running when it `join`s. If you remove your answer, I can remove the question.